# ¿Como ocultar una columna de una tabla para un usuario en especifico?

Tags: php, bootstrap

quiero ocultar toda la columna para un usuario especifico [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  if($_SESSION["perfil"]=="Administrador"){
              $pdf='<img src="vistas/img/plantilla/pdf.png" class="abrirPDF" docuCliente="'.$value["documento"].'" width="45px" style="cursor:pointer;">';}
            else{
              $pdf="";}

            echo '<tr>

                    <td>'.($key+1).'</td>

                    <td>'.$value["nombre"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$value["documento"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$value["email"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$value["telefono"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$value["direccion"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$pdf.'</td>

                    <td>'.$estado.'</td>

                    <td>'.$diasF.' día(s)</td>
```

digamos aca lo hago con lo que esta adentro en certificacion pero quiero es ocultar toda la columna ayuda gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESPUESTA RAPIDA**

Realizar una comprobación, en caso de que el usuario Sea diferente mostramos la columna.

```
 if($_SESSION["perfil"]=="Administrador"){
              $pdf='<img src="vistas/img/plantilla/pdf.png" class="abrirPDF" docuCliente="'.$value["documento"].'" width="45px" style="cursor:pointer;">';}
            else{
              $pdf="";}

            echo '<tr>

                    <td>'.($key+1).'</td>

                    <td>'.$value["nombre"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$value["documento"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$value["email"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$value["telefono"].'</td>'+
             if($_SESSION["perfil"] !="Usuarioespecifico"){
                      '<td>'.$value["direccion"].'</td>'

               }
                   '<td>'.$pdf.'</td>

                    <td>'.$estado.'</td>

                    <td>'.$diasF.' día(s)</td>
```

---

```
if($_SESSION["perfil"] !="Usuarioespecifico"){
        Mostramos la columna

}
```